# Как записать данные из переменной в файл?

Tags: java, android

Как записать данные из double probinres в FILENAME?

```
 public void onSettingsMenuClick(MenuItem item) {
            FileOutputStream fos=null;
            try {
                fos= openFileOutput(FILENAME,MODE_PRIVATE);//open stream
                fos.write(probinres.getBytes());//эта строка неверна. как записать данные из probinres в FILENAME?
                Toast.makeText(this, "Файл сохранен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch(IOException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            finally{
                try{
                    if(fos!=null)
                        fos.close();//output stream is closed
                }
                catch(IOException ex){

                    Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вот [неплохой урок](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/138-urok-75-hranenie-dannyh-rabota-s-fajlami.html) на старандроид

Answer (score 0):

ошибка заключалась в следующем: 
     fos.write(probinres.getBytes()); где `probinres`, являясь double, не могла быть прочтена `.getBytes()`

```
.getBytes() не может прочитать float, double и т. д.  зато это может сделать String
```

я поступил следующим образом:

```
public void onSettingsMenuClick(MenuItem item) {
        FileOutputStream fos=null;
textprobinres= String.valueOf(probinres);//данные из double probinres в String
        try {
            fos= openFileOutput(FILENAME,MODE_PRIVATE);//open stream
            fos.write(textprobinres.getBytes());//прошла запись в FILENAME
            Toast.makeText(this, "Файл сохранен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        finally{
            try{
                if(fos!=null)
                    fos.close();//output stream is closed
            }
            catch(IOException ex){

                Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```